# Console apps don't work in Powershell

Tags: windows-server-2003, powershell, path

I've inherited a Windows Server 2003 r2 box.  I've got a Powershell script that I'd need to get running on the machine, but something seems terribly wrong with the system.  For example, opening a Powershell console and entering `ipconfig` gets the following response:

```
The term 'ipconfig' is not recognized as a cmdlet, function, operable program, or script file.  Verify the term and try again.
```

My Powershell script is trying to call pscp.exe (from the putty project), and it gets the same error as above.

My first suspicion was that it was a path issue, and sure enough, when I opened up the environment variables window, the `PATH` variable didn't even exist.  So I created it, and made sure the directory containing `pscp` was listed there. Still no dice.

Running the same commands (ipconfig, or pscp) in cmd.exe works as expected once I added some basic entries to the `PATH` variable (%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;).

`$env:path` in Powershell returns the values of the `PATH` variable, but powershell still won't execute programs that are in those directories.  `get-host | select version` returns 1.0.0.0.

Any hints?

Comment: Do you have `%PATHEXT%` set? (It should list at least `.exe;.cmd;.bat`)

Comment: Adding %PATHEXT% got the default windows console programs to work, but not PSCP that I'm depending on.

Comment: Copying the pscp.exe file into the same directory as my ps1 file is working for now.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your environment is a little messed up. Here are a couple of extra troubleshooting steps, hopefully one of them will give more useful information:

Try to run the command using the full path: c:\windows\system32\ipconfig.exe

Try the invoke-expression cmdlet:

```
invoke-expression -command "ipconfig"
```

or:

```
invoke-expression -command "c:\windows\system32\ipconfig.exe"
```

Try using the .Net process provider (you won't be able to see the results of the call, but it will give you some information about it that might be useful):

```
[System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start("c:\windows\system32\ipconfig.exe")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try running `powershell -NoProfile` and see if things work. If so. then your problem is the profile script, which you can edit with `notepad $profile`.

Try opening a CMD window and run `ipconfig` there. If it works in CMD but not in PowerShell, then compare the environment found in each. The easiest way is probably to run `set` in CMD and to run `cmd.exe /C set` in the PowerShell window and compare the results.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little odd to see your PATH expressed in terms of other environment variables.  I wonder if that could be making things wonky.

For instance, here's what I would expect to see in your PATH variable (assuming that C: is your primary install drive):

```
PATH=C:\Windows\System32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;
```